# Update custom application

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-alternatives

I'm developing Java application that runs on Ubuntu. Application is something like simple web service and is always running.

I need to solve application update problem. I'm planing to place new application version on web and somehow place information with version number. I need service or script that could run one time per day to check is there new version on web and if it is there download it, stop my java program, overwrite jar file and run it. What is the best way to do this?

Maybe there are some standard solutions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple solution, you could make a `cron` job to make these steps. A more Java-like solution would be using *JNLP (Java Web Start)* or *IcedTea-Web* (its open source reimplementation).